# Can I get counts of rows meeting conditions for each month as one table with each column being a different count?

Tags: mysql

For example, my table has something like:

record_id,date_in,date_start,date_order,date_deliver

I want to get the counts, by month, for the total number of records, counts for when the difference between date_in and date_start exceeds 2 days, counts for when the difference between date_start and date_order exceed 1 day, and counts for when the difference between date_order and date_deliver exceed 10 days.

I can run separate queries that gets me each of those, but I can't figure out how to get those in one result/query. I'd maybe like to do this as a stored procedure if it works as one table.

Queries I've tried that work, just not as one result:

```
select month(date_in) MONTH, count(*) from MYTABLE where YEAR(date_in)=2021 group by MONTH(date_in);
select month(date_in) MONTH, count(*) from MYTABLE where TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date_in,date_start) > 2 and YEAR(date_in)=2021 group by MONTH(date_in);
select month(date_in) MONTH, count(*) from MYTABLE where TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date_start,date_order) > 1 and YEAR(date_in)=2021 group by MONTH(date_in);
select month(date_in) MONTH, count(*) from MYTABLE where TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date_order,date_deliver) > 10 and YEAR(date_in)=2021 group by MONTH(date_in);
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT MONTH(date_in) `month`, 
       COUNT(*),
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date_in,date_start) > 2),
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date_start,date_order) > 1),
       SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,date_order,date_deliver) > 10)
FROM mytable 
WHERE YEAR(date_in)=2021
GROUP BY MONTH(date_in);
```